# Внутренняя тень градиентом

Tags: css, градиент

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно сделать внутреннюю тень у блока, но что бы она была под углом `45deg`.

Я пробовал такое сделать обычной тенью, но оно не так выглядит, как надо:

```css
.shadow {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Мне пришла в голову идея: сделать тень градиентом. Но я не знаю как.

Пример нужной тени:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю попробовать `background`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

div {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  margin: auto;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 70%, black 100%)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: О, а с картинкой на фоне такое можно сделать?

Comment: @АлександрАнтонов, не наглейте :) Что бы была картинка, добавьте ещё одну строчку в `background` с адресом картинки. (Пример: `background: linear-gradient(...), linear-gradient(...), url(...)`)

Comment: Спасибки вам :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.cover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 60px 0 0 0;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 10%, 1);
}

.shadow {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 200px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1), -10px -10px 200px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересно, но визуально не похоже :) Очень чёткая граница между тенью и ромбом.

Comment: @Qwertiy, но он старался и это надо ценить :)

Comment: @АлександрАнтонов, согласен :)