# Внутрення круговая тень градиентом

Tags: css, градиент

Всем привет! Я недавно задавал, как сделать [наклонную внутреннюю тень](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635189/%D0%92%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Теперь ко мне пришла необходимость создать такую же тень, то круговую. У меня появилась идея создать несколькими градиентами, но оно выглядит скорее, как ромб.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background:
    linear-gradient(-115deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(-155deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(115deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(155deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(-70deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(-20deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(70deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(20deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 70%, black 100%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 70%, black 100%)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для круговых теней существует `radial-gradient`:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 40%, black 80%, black 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Не знал, что есть круговой градиент. Спасибо :)