# Внутренняя крестовая тень градиентом

Tags: css, градиент

Всем пример! Я недавно задавал, как сделать наклонную [круговую внутреннюю тень](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635362/%D0%92%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Теперь ко мне пришла необходимость создать такую же тень, только в виде крестика. Как можно такое осуществить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, что вы такое делаете с этими градиентами?)

Comment: @Yuri, нечто странное :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаёшь несколько градиентов, устанавливаешь им размер 50% 50% (ширина и высота). Ну а там дело техники

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, transparent 40%, transparent 50%, transparent 60%, black 100%) no-repeat 0px 0px,
    linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, transparent 40%, transparent 50%, transparent 60%, black 100%) no-repeat 100px 0px,
    linear-gradient(135deg, black 0%, transparent 40%, transparent 50%, transparent 60%, black 100%) no-repeat 0px 100px,
    linear-gradient(-135deg, black 0%, transparent 40%, transparent 50%, transparent 60%, black 100%) no-repeat 100px 100px,
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHM0K.png);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```